# Converting .dbf to .xlsx in R

Tags: r, excel, gis

Hey so I'm pretty new at this. I am trying to convert a dbf file from GIS to an excel form in RStudio so its easier to play with. Appreciate any help that comes my way:
Keeps showing the error:could not find function "convert"

```
      library(foreign)
      library(translations)
        install.packages("translate")
        install.packages("rio")
        install.packages("mtcars")
        library(car)
        files <- list.files(path="D:/___Transfer/masteraltkrs", pattern="*.dbf", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

        for(i in files) {
          oldFile <- i
          sub(".dbf",".xlsx",i)
          convert(oldFile, i)
          }
```

Comment: You have only installed the package `rio` but you still need to load it with `library(rio)` to be able to use the function `rio::convert`